# Creating a new list based on matching elements of two nested lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, each containing multiple sublists of two elements each. I want to create a new list that contains only those sublists where the first element of the sublist existed in both original lists. I can do it in flat lists using list comprehension or set intersections, but struggle when it is with lists of lists.

For example (using data from a csv file):

```
apairs = [['apple', '2.4\n'], ['banana', '2.3\n'], ['orange', '1.8\n'], 
          ['apple', '1.6\n']]
bpairs = [['grape', '2.3\n'], ['apple', '2.1\n'], ['apple', '2.0\n'],
          ['peach', '1.9\n'], ['plum', '1.5\n']]
```

I would like a new list created that includes only the pairs where the first element of a sublist exists in both outer lists and only the first instance of a pair with element is included. I want the pair to be extracted from the 'alist' so that it includes the second element of that pair. So my desired output in this case is:

```
intersectpairs = [['apple, '2.4\n']]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you could just extract the lists, then extract the data from those lists and put it in a list. This is not the most efficient way, but it is indeed a nice backup plan in case nothing else works.

Comment: Iterate through bpairs and put the fruit names into a hashset, Then create a new list and iterate through apairs and see if they have membership in the set, would that work?

Comment: Thanks all for the help! All presented solutions work with the case I provided, but I would also like to only include each pair once in the new list. If there are multiple pairs containing the same first element in either list, I would like to only include the first one in a new list (such that the new list contains pairs where the first element is unique). Sorry for the lack of clarification - I have updated the original post to reflect this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

How about list comprehension?

```
from operator import itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)

[val for val in apairs if first(val) in map(first, bpairs)]

[['apple', '2.4\n']]
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggestions on how this could be modified to ensure there are no pairs with identical first elements in the new list? I have updated the original post to include this info. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
intersectpairs = []
bfruits = set()

for i in range(0,len(bpairs)):
    bfruits.add(bpairs[i][0])

for i in range(0,len(apairs)):
    if apairs[i][0] in bfruits:
       intersectpairs.append(apairs[i])

print (intersectpairs)
```

Comment: Thank you! How could you modify this code to avoid pairs with identical first elements in the output list? Sorry, should have included this info in the original post - have updated it now.

Comment: just change the "if apairs[i][0] in bfruits:" to "if apairs[i][0] not in bfruits"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over both the list and compare the value. A sample code snippet for the same is :

```
apairs = [['apple', '2.4\n'], ['banana', '2.3\n'], ['orange', '1.8\n']]
bpairs = [['grape', '2.3\n'], ['apple', '2.1\n'], ['peach', '1.9\n'], ['plum',     '1.5\n']]
intersectpairs = []
for i in apairs:
    for j in bpairs:
        if (i[0]==j[0]):
            intersectpairs.append(i)
print(intersectpairs)

[['apple', '2.4\n']]
```

Or if you want to use list comprehension

```
[i for i in apairs for j in bpairs if(i[0]==j[0])]
```

This would return a list of list with matching element in both the list.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how this could be modified to ensure there are no pairs with the same first element in the new list? I have updated the example above and this code includes a few pairs that include 'apple'. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! I figured out a solution based on @Mayank Mehtani's answer. For people with this problem in the future, this code solves the problem:

```
intersectionpairs = []
intersectionfruits = []
bfruits = set()

for i in range(0,len(bpairs)):
    bfruits.add(bpairs[i][0])
print('bfruits:', bfruits)
for i in range(0,len(apairs)):
    if apairs[i][0] in bfruits and apairs[i][0] not in intersectionfruits:
        intersectionfruits.append(apairs[i][0])
        intersectionpairs.append(apairs[i])
```

May not be the most efficient or sophisticated answer, but it gives the desired output!